# Add custom column in AspNetRoles results in Invalid Column Name Discriminator

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2, asp.net-roles, discriminator

I'm using ASP.NET MVC5 with **Identity 2** framework, *Database first*

I'm trying to custom `AspNetRoles`, by adding a column called *MyCustomColumn*

However, my app crashes because :

> Invalid Column Name Discriminator

There is a lot of resources on SO and elsewhere on the web, but most of them are with CodeFirst approach and I can't use them in my app.

How to deal with it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, as I spend some hours to find a solution, I post it here, if it could help someone else.

First, in `AspNetRoles`, create your custom column **AND** a column called `Discriminator` (which is a `nvarchar(max)` ). Update your `.edmx`

Then, we have to create a class which inherits from `IdentityRole`. We will use this class to access our custom column we just created :

*In Models folder*

```
public ApplicationRole()
        : base() { }

    public ApplicationRole(string name, long myCustomValue)
        : base(name)
    {
        MyCustomValue = myCustomValue;
    }

    public virtual long MyCustomValue { get; set; }
```

Then, let's create a class which inherits from `RoleManager<ApplicationRole>`.
I placed it in `IdentityConfig.cs`, but maybe it's a best practice to place it elsewhere...
For information, I get inspired by [this blog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/790720/ASP-NET-Identity-Customizing-Users-and-Roles), *Re-Implementing RoleStore and ApplicationRoleManager* paragraph

```
public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(
        IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> roleStore)
        : base(roleStore)
    {
    }
    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(
        IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options, IOwinContext context)
    {
        return new ApplicationRoleManager(
            new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(context.Get<ApplicationDbContext>()));
    }
}
```

`ApplicationRoleManager` has a constructor which calls our previously created `ApplicationRole` class.

Now we have to register our `ApplicationRoleManager` at startup, so we have to add this line after the others `CreatePerOwinContext`

*In App_Start\Startup.auth.cs, ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) method*

```
app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationRoleManager>(ApplicationRoleManager.Create);
```

So now we can use our `ApplicationRoleManager`, correctly instanciated :

```
var rm = new ApplicationRoleManager(new RoleStore<ApplicationRole>(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```

And then use it as we want

```
var roleName = rm.FindByName("Admin");
string myCustomData = roleName.CustomData.ToString();
```

Comment: this is useful, but why we need to add Discriminator field to the AspNetRoles table?

Answer (score 7):

Actually, none of this is necessary. Most likely you failed to update your context to inherit from `IdentityDbContext<TUser, TRole, TKey, TUserLogin, TUserRole, TUserClaim>`, rather than the default of `IdentityDbContext<TUser>`. Since you did not pass your custom role entity as the `TRole` type parameter, the context instead uses `IdentityRole` as the class type. It then creates a table for `IdentityRole`, sees that your custom role inherits from `IdentityRole`, and therefore adds the Discriminator column so that it can tell the different between an instance of `IdentityRole` and your custom role, in the database (single table inheritance is the default strategy EF employs).

This will *technically* work, but your custom role will never actually be utilized. Use the right generic abstract context class, and you'll be fine.

For what it's worth, you should do away with the EDMX stuff, as well. It's deprecated, buggy, and unnecessary. Despite the name, "Code First" can be used with an existing database or to create a new one.

**DON'T**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

**DO**

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but a sample of code would be very appreciated (I'm quite new with Identity). Also, this project is DB-first, so even if Code-first is very interesting, I can't use it here.

Comment: Yes, you can. That's my point. Code first, despite the name, can be used with an existing database. Database first and Model first (EDMX) has been deprecated in favor of Code fist.

Comment: Also, sample code is pretty self-explanatory, but I updated my answer to spell it out more explicitly.